# Include quote marks inside a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to include quotes into my string to add to a text box, i am using this code.

```
 t.AppendText("Dim Choice" & count + " As String = " + "Your New Name is:  & pt1 + "" & pt2 +" + vbNewLine)
```

but it doesnt work, i want it to output like so:

```
Dim Choice As String = "Your New Name is: NAME_HERE"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes.  In VB.NET, you use double quotes - "":

```
t.AppendText("Dim Choice" + count.ToString() + " As String = ""Your New Name is: "  + pt1 + " " + pt2 + """" + vbNewLine)
```

This would print as:

```
Dim Choice1 As String = "Your New Name is: NAME HERE"
```

Assuming count = 1 (Integer), pt1 = "NAME" and pt2 = "HERE".

If `count` is not an Integer, you can drop the ToString() call.

In C#, you escape the " by using a \, like this:

```
t.AppendText("string Choice" + count.ToString() + " = \"Your New Name is: " + pt1 + " " + pt2 + "\"\n");
```

Which would print as:

```
string Choice1 = "Your new Name is: NAME HERE";
```

Comment: On the last bit of the code """ + vbNewLine) has and error: "String constant must end with double quotes"

Comment: I updated the end of the code to use 4 " - i.e., """".  I put three by accident initially.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

As Tim said, simply replace each occurrence of `"` inside the string with `""`.

Furthermore, use `String.Format` to make the code more readable:

```
t.AppendText( _
    String.Format( _
        "Dim Choice{0} As String = ""Your New Name is: {1} {2}""{3}", _
        count, pt1, pt2, vbNewLine)
```

Depending on the type of your `t`, there might even be a method that supports format strings directly, i.e. perhaps you can even simplify the above to the following:

```
t.AppendText( _
    "Dim Choice{0} As String = ""Your New Name is: {1} {2}""{3}", _
    count, pt1, pt2, vbNewLine)
```

Comment: +1 for String.Format.  I'm a big fan of code readability (even though I keep forgetting simple things like String.Format...maybe I'll get it down when I grow up :) ).

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape them, however you cannot dynamically generate variable names as you're attempting to here:

```
"Dim Choice" & count + " As String = "
```

this will just be a string.

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to dynamically generate variable names, since he says he's trying to put the string in a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Chr Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with the [quotes ASCII Code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm): 34 to have a result as this:

```
t.Append(Dim Choice As String = " & Chr(34) & "Your New Name is: NAME_HERE" & Chr(34))
```

Comment: Don’t use `Chr` here, it just makes it less readable. Nobody would use `(char)34` in C#, you’d use `\"`. The same is true in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Although escaping the string is the *correct* way of doing things it is not always the easiest to read. Consider trying to create the following string:

```
Blank "" Full "Full" and another Blank ""
```

To escape this you need to do the following:

```
"Blank """" Full ""Full"" and another Blank """""
```

But if you using `String.Format` with `Chr(34)` you can do the following:

```
String.Format("Blank {0}{0} Full {0}Full{0} and another Blank {0}{0}", Chr(34))
```

This is an option if you find this easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

In `VB .Net` you can do this :

Assuming `count = 1 (Integer), pt1 = "NAME" and pt2 = "HERE"`.

```
t.AppendText("Dim Choice" & count.Tostring() + " As String ="+ CHR(34) + "Your New Name is: " & pt1 + "_" & pt2 +CHR(34) + vbNewLine)
```

The output will be
Dim Choice As String = "Your New Name is: NAME_HERE"

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Me.TextBox" + (box).ToString + ".Name = " + Chr(34) + "TextBox" + box.ToString + Chr(34)
```

Result:

```
Me.TExtBox123.Name = "TextBox123"
```

where `box = 123` integer
Using VB.Basic 2019.