# string escape conversion vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, escaping

I need to convert this string to the proper form in my vb,net code

```
if (c == '"') {
s.Append('"');
} else if (c == '\\') {
s.Append('\\');
} else if (c == '/') {
s.Append('/');
} else if (c == 'b') {
s.Append('\b');
} else if (c == 'f') {
s.Append('\f');
} else if (c == 'n') {
s.Append('\n');
} else if (c == 'r') {
s.Append('\r');
} else if (c == 't') {
s.Append('\t');
} else if (c == 'u') {
```

This is inappropriately converted to

```
If c = """"c Then
    s.Append(""""c)
ElseIf c = "\"c Then
    s.Append("\"c)
ElseIf c = "/"c Then
    s.Append("/"c)
ElseIf c = "b"c Then
    s.Append(ControlChars.Back)
ElseIf c = "f"c Then
    s.Append(ControlChars.FormFeed)
ElseIf c = "n"c Then
    s.Append(ControlChars.Lf)
ElseIf c = "r"c Then
    s.Append(ControlChars.Cr)
ElseIf c = "t"c Then
    s.Append(ControlChars.Tab)
ElseIf c = "u"c Then
```

Can someone help me do the right string escape codes

thanks

Edit

thansk to all the people helping me so far, but the main question is

how do you quote like this `'"'` in vb, as i cant use the single quote here

Comment: How are you doing the conversion?

Comment: It's maybe off topic, but do you have a good reason for doing `s.Append(c)` in 17 lines?

Comment: this looks quiet intresting. Where do you get this string from? Could you use regex to solve this? Please show us, whioch chars has to been replaced and how do you load the string.

Comment: Austin Salonen am using an online converter to convert

Comment: @Otiel its an if statement, that performs a test. The original code is not mine, just trying to convert to vb.net

Comment: Which part is "inappropriate"? The control characters are correct. Does this not compile? Or is it giving you incorrect results? What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: @Smith could you post the original code then?

Comment: How about posting `given` -> `expected` -> `received`?

Comment: @AustinSalonen am just trying to find a way to quote a quotation mark in vb.net

Comment: The conversion is correct - maybe it is your understanding of how double quotes are escaped in VB.NET? Have a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239872/include-quote-marks-inside-a-string/7256852#7256852)

Comment: Thanks guys, i found another way to solve it

Comment: I too, cannot see anything wrong with the conversion.  It looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converted code is correct.  You can use ChrW(34) if that makes you feel more comfortable:

```
    If c = ChrW(34) Then
        s.Append(ChrW(34))
    '' etc...
```

Comment: the converted code is not correct, and it does not give the expected output as the c# version.