# How to split a string with " in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So initially, I thought I was doing something wrong as I can't find anyone else trying to do this, but maybe I just do things in a more complicated way. Anyway; I have this line of code:

```
newtab(listA(i).Split("""))
```

That, in my mind should work, because why wouldn't you want to split a string by ", right? Well apparently vb.NET doesn't like that.

Comment: if you have fields quite enclosed, you dont want to split by quote or you will get lots of empty elements in the returned array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include quote marks inside a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239872/include-quote-marks-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newtab(listA(i).Split(""""))
```

You need to use "" for a " within "..."

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
newtab(listA(i).Split("\""))
```

Comment: Still returns the same error of it thinking that it must end with a double quote.

Comment: what does your string look like?

Comment: VB doesnt use escape chars so "\" doesnt help.

Comment: How about something like this Split(""".ToCharArray())

Comment: Or newtab(listA(i).Split(Convert.ToChar(147)))